# enabling a constructor with sfinae if given template argument provides a type definition

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, sfinae

I want to enable one and only one of two constructors in a template class depending if the given type as template parameter defines a type or not.

Here I want to add the defined type from the given template as additional parameter in the constructor and forward this parameter if it is present. But see:

```
class A
{  // this class did not provide ConstructorParms type definition
    public:
        A( int i) {}
};

class B
{  // this class provide the type ConstructorParms
    public:
        using ConstructorParms= double;

        B( double d, int i) {}
};


template <typename T>
class Check: public T
{
    public:
        // ??? enable_if T has typename T::ConstructorParms
        Check( typename T::ConstructorParms parms, int i): T( parms, i) {}

        // ??? enable_if T has NOT typename T::ConstructorParms
        Check( int i): T(i){}
};

int main()
{
    Check<A> ca(9);             
    Check<B> cb(1.23, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

I run into trouble, because the constructor "method" itself has no template parm. Any idea?

Attention ( cause of given answer ):
The code fragment is really simplified. Forwarding to the parent constructor with using is not an option, because the real world class Check needs some parameters for them self. This makes forwarding to the parent constructor not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve this using SFINAE, but there is a much easier solution since C++11:
Inheriting constructors.

```
template <typename T>
class Check: public T
{
    public:
        using T::T;
};
```

---

In case the constructor does more than only forwarding; use this general solution:

```
#include <type_traits>

template< typename T >
struct HasCtorParamTypedef
{
    template< typename U,
              typename = typename U::ConstructorParms >
    static int f( U );

    static void f( ... );

    static const bool value = std::is_same<decltype(f(std::declval<T>())), int>::value;
};

template <typename T>
struct Check: public T
{
        // Is only enabled if T does have the typedef
        template <typename U = T,
                  typename = typename std::enable_if<HasCtorParamTypedef<U>::value>::type >
        Check( typename U::ConstructorParms parms, int i): T( parms, i) {}

        // Is only enabled if T does **not** have the typedef
        template <typename U = T,
                  typename = typename std::enable_if<!HasCtorParamTypedef<U>::value>::type >
        Check( int i ): T(i){}
};
```

Comment: But he wants to extend the constructor, not forward it.

Comment: Sorry, my example is simplified! The real world code needs some own constructor parms for the class Check itself. So simply constructor forwarding will not work. Thanks!

Comment: Added sth. - does that help more?

Comment: Can you explain the line `typename = decltype(U(0))` Is it a problem if type T can not be initialized with 0? Real world code should work not only work with int type. But at first: I can't read the `typename =`. Thanks for learning!

Comment: Okay, the most general solution is appended. It uses exactly what you want, but is a little bit more complicated; And what do you mean by "I can't read the `typename =`"? That's a template parameter without a name but with a default argument, just like a function parameter without a name.

Comment: Thanks! But could you provide some explanation on the expression `typename = ... ` in the template parameter list? Never seen that before.

Comment: @Klaus It is explained in my last comment - it is a template parameter, without a name, with a default argument.